# Vb.net Read From Console When Using A Windows Form Application

Tags: vb.net, forms, console

Hi all I have a problem with reading and writing to the console from a windows form application.

I am running visual studios 2010 and I am coding in visual basic.

The current code that I have is as follows:

```
Declare Function AttachConsole Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwProcessId As Int32) As Boolean
Declare Function FreeConsole Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Boolean
System.Console.Write("abc")
Dim test as string = Console.ReadLine()
System.Console.Clear()
ect
FreeConsole()
```

With the following code I can write to the console but I cannot read from it, any ideas?